# Kotlin checked exceptions alternative

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, kotlin

Since Kotlin doesn't support checked exceptions then how to make a programmer aware that a method may throw exception

Simple example:

```
class Calculator (value: Int = 0) {

    fun divide (dividend: BigDecimal, divider: BigDecimal) : BigDecimal {
        return dividend / divider
    }
}
```

Obviously the divide method may throw `java.lang.ArithmeticException: Division by zero` exception and the creator of the library needs to warn the user of the class to put the invoke in a `try-catch` clause

What's the mechanism for that awareness in Kotlin?

Comment: ArithmeticException is not _checked exception_, so even in JAVA programmer wouldn't be warned. You would have to use eg. IOException

Comment: @Przemo Really, is that so? Thank you for that info

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the fact that the language doesn't have a construct to make this explicit, the only thing left is: implicitly.

For example by putting javadoc that clearly tells the user of the method about what/why exceptions might be thrown at him. Or you use the [@Throws](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-throws/) annotation.

Maybe, maybe the kotlin team will add *compiler warnings* at some point to make up for this ( see [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/in-future-could-kotlin-have-checked-exception/1579) ).

Comment: "Implicit error handling."- Kotlin, 2016

Answer (score 3):

You can return Try so that client can call isSuccess or isFailure http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2017/12/kotlin-try-type-for-functional.html

You can also return nullable type BigDecimal? so that client will know that the value might not exist (when divided by zero you can return null).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `kotlin.Result` https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/

```
import java.math.BigDecimal

class Calculator() {

    private companion object {
        val ZERO: BigDecimal = BigDecimal(0)
    }

    fun divide(dividend: BigDecimal, divider: BigDecimal): Result<BigDecimal> =
        if (divider != ZERO) {
            val ans = dividend.divide(divider)
            Result.success(ans)
        } else {
            val throwable = ArithmeticException("Division by zero")
            Result.failure(throwable)
        }
}
```